# Hosting solutions for 10,000 daily users, asp .net 4, sql server 2008 R2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I've run a custom built social network on top of asp .net mvc & sql server 2005 for the last 2 years on [discountasp .net](http://www.discountasp.net/)

I've been satisfied with the value as it's cost me around $500 over that period. The limitations are 1GB storage which meant the only media on the network I could afford was 1 profile photo per member and 1GB database, which means I have to periodically delete all my logs and I'm left with about 600MB sized sql database.

The social network has been linearly growing consistently since inception and this solution will not hold of for 2 much longer.

I also wish to build a whole new much more involved site, richer in media and many more options for user interaction, meaning a database schema double the size and much higher db traffic.

I would like to find a cost effective (like $300 per month or less) solution to host the new site which would have around 10,000 daily visitors. Perhaps I might need a 10GB sql server database, which much be 2008 R2 because I've got cool spacial stuff going on.

Also I'm wondering if I can put my media on a separate cheap hosting solution where I don't have to pay through the roof for storage and bandwidth and implement it so users to seemlinessly switch servers (and hosts) while they use the application. Has anyone ever done this? If so which host did you use for your media?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could store your media on [Amazon's S3 storage network](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). This is a dump storage solution. It won't be able to handle scripts and any work but as a mechanism to store files it will be what your after!

You can also combine with it with [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). This will then serve your content from a location from different places depending on what is quickest for each indivdual user.

Quote from Amazon:

> Using a network of edge locations around the world, Amazon CloudFront caches copies of your content close to end users, lowering latency when they download or stream your objects. The service also gives you the high, sustained data transfer rates needed to deliver large popular objects to end users at scale.

You don't have to use Amazon of course, there are a number of content delivery networks, but that is the one I know about.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2. You can easily scale there. 10,000 visitors can be easily handled by using a CPU intensive instance. And, it will cost you less than $100 per month

Answer (score 0):

I'm maybe being old fashioned but I'd just get a (managed/semi-managed) dedicated server. If you can figure out Amazon AWS then you can handle your own server.

You can easily find a server with >1TB HDD and >10TB bandwidth for well under $300 managed.